# camera preview size of OpenCV doesn't change on android

Tags: android, opencv

I've used CameraBridgeViewBase on OpenCV 3.2 to display device camera preview, But seems it isn't changed using SetMaxFrameSize method. Below is the snippet code which I used:

```
camBridgeView = new JavaCameraView(context, 0);
camBridgeView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
camBridgeView.setMaxFrameSize(1280,960);
```

The frame size is always somthing like 480*320. What's the problem?